# how to run NSThread when app goes to background

Tags: iphone, nsthread

I need to control the volume of device when app is in background so for this i use following code

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
back=1;

NSLog(@"Enter in the back");
float v=1.0f;

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(changeCounter) toTarget:self withObject:_viewController];
```

}

changeCounter has infinite loop.But when i run the code and send the app to back.loop runs only for one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to request a background task from the [UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`. There are examples in the [Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) (See the Completing a Finite-Length Task in the Background section).

Comment: how can I stop then running task when app is comming in foreground

Comment: You need to keep track of the UIBackgroundTask returned from the `beginBackground...` call and on applicationDidBecome active call application `endTask:` if the task is not invalid.

Comment: applicationDidBecome is not called untill loop in bgtask finishes

Comment: What is the issue then. If the task done by time the app becomes active then it will be stopped. But if it is still running the place to stop it is in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` by calling `[application endTask:myTaskRef];` and stopping any async operations if necessary.

Comment: you are not getting ..applicationDidBecomeActive is not going to be called untill bgtask ends